# JSson.NET integer parsing fails in portable class library

Tags: json.net, portable-class-library

I'm using Json.NET version 5.0.6 in a Portable Class Library project (which is used in a Windows Phone 8 application project). I have JSON data which includes the following value.

```
{ 
  [..]
 "Probability": 50, 
  [..] 
}
```

Now, If I define Probability as integer in the model, the deserialization fails with System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

```
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.Int32Parse(Char[] chars, Int32 start, Int32 length)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumber()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAsInt32Internal()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsInt32()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.<>c__DisplayClass6`1.<DeserializeObjectAsync>b__5()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
```

When I change the property type in the model to string, deserialization goes through just fine and the field gets value "50". Is this a bug in Json.NET? Looks like that to me. I was searching around for better place to post this but apparent SO is the preferred channel now.

Comment: You should be able to report the bug on http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I don't know what was the problem earlier but I couldn't reproduce this in a PCL project called from console or WP8 app. Now the server is returning Probability as "50.0" (without quotes) so I had to change data type to double for parsing to work. I guess previously I had lost the ".0" from the value before generating proper JSON DTOs.